# How do I divide tasks between frontend and backend properly?

Tags: javascript, python, vue.js, frontend, backend

I have an idea to make something similar to Workflowy but with some new features. 
(Workflowy is basically a note-taking app which beautifully organises all your notes as an endless tree)

At first, I implemented the logic in Python. It works in a terminal by printing notes line-by-line and then waiting for the command.

Is this a good idea to keep all the logic at the server and use JS only to render items and to send commands to the server?

For instance, if I want to move the entire folder into another folder, there are two ways of doing this:

- Way 1: With Python which receives a command from JS 'move folder x to folder y', processes it and sends back a result to render.
- Way 2: With JS which then has to understand all the folder structure and logic. In this case, the app will use a server only for storing data.

I have a feeling that way 2 (using JS to understand all the logic and Python only for saving data) is more appropriate, but this means that I have to rewrite everything from scratch.

Is the way 1 also reasonable?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a question for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ . I'm not aware of WorkFlowy. Probably a reasonable way is a combination of them. You may want to rely on frontend logic for offline mode. You may want to rely on backend logic if the task is too resource-intensive for frontend or can be abused by a client. This is one of scenarios when isomorphic JS can be beneficial if you don't want to write the same thing twice in different languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the application you are making.

Like if you want to display thousands of data in html file, and data are stored in a json file. If you send html file and json file to the client from the server, then on the client side, you run a script that reads json file and displays it in html, then it will be slower, because client device may not be that powerful as the server is.

So for performance, use heavy tasks on server side, this may cause little more internet usage because as the client has no data in formatted manner, whenever new task on data is to be performed, you have to request the server again.

But for opposite case, you can save internet and little low performance. Here you can do some heavy tasks on client side.

It also depends on which device is used at client side.